# Android manifest xml file

Tags: android, android-manifest

After deleting an Android xml activity file, got problem in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

What can be done to cure the issue?
In an activity created an EditText field and gave it a green background. And also gave Relative layout background a custom color, but nothing happened to the layout and the text field. So decided to delete the Relative layout(not main layout) to create a fresh one. And got the problem in Android manifest xml file.

**Code:**

```
layout seekbarlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutwithseekbar);
seekbarlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(xxxxxxxx));

text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textwithseekbar);
text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(xxxxxxx));
```

Comment: We are not a seers :P Post manifest, and xmls

Comment: so what's your problem?

Comment: The problem is parse exception for ....... The markup in the document preceeding the root element must be well formed.

Comment: <<<<<<< Original
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.counter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

Answer (score 0):

Well, your RelativeLayout must had EditText in it, so when you removed RelativeLayout, the EditText should be removed with it.

> Structure:
>
> ```
> main_layout.xml
> |--+ RelativeLayout (layoutwithseekbar)
>    |--> EditText (textwithseekbar)
> ```

try making new layout set id *layoutwithseekbar* on it and put EditText in it

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layoutwithseekbar android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/textwithseekbar" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ok. I am going to try it.